# Как задать данные из json в dropdown input в Angular?

Tags: angular

Есть приложение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно задать данные в Dropdown `button` из JSON. Данные поступают отсюда:

```
https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all
```

Почти решил проблему, но почему то вместо данных приходит `[object Object]`.

Вот код:

```
app.component.html
<div class="row">
<div class="dropdown col-sm-12" >
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" 
id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria- 
expanded="false">
        Dropdown button
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton"
    >
        <app-dog *ngFor="let d of dogs" 
        [dog]="d">
        <a class="dropdown-item">{{ d.message }}</a>
        </app-dog>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

app.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DogsService } from './dog/dogs.service';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
 providers: [DogsService]
})
export class AppComponent {

dogs = [];

constructor(private dogsService: DogsService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.dogsService.getDogs().subscribe(dogs =>
    {
        this.dogs = dogs
    })
}
}
```

**dogs.services.ts**

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators/'; 

@Injectable()
export class DogsService {

constructor(private http: Http) {}

getDogs()  {
    return this.http.get('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all')
    .pipe(map(response => response.json()))
    .pipe(map(response => response.message))
    .pipe(map(response => {
        return response.map(d => {
            return {
                message: d.message
            }
        })
    }))

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

D.message это объект. Зайди в объект и выводы значения по индексу. Ти d.message[0]. Не знаю, как в ng, но в ваниле это обычный for I++

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую.

Answer (score 0):

Добавь Pipe 'keys' на основе Object.keys;

```
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'keys'})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, args: any[] = null): any {
        return Object.keys(value);
    }
}
```

И использовать уже его для вывода инфы:

```
 <div *ngFor="let key of obj | keys">
```